# Replace [ and ] in a string with regex

Tags: regex, puppet

How to delete `[` and `]` characters in a string with Regex ?

I'm using the Puppet DSL function regsubst :

```
regsubst($::env, '\[\]', '', 'G')
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brackets are metacharacters in a regex and need to be escaped (and put in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) if you want to match either one):

```
regsubst($::env, '[\[\]]', '', 'G')
```

Your version was only matching the exact string `[]`.

In a regex, `[abc]` means "Match one of the following: `a`, `b` or `c`".

Comment: Well, technically, ``[][]`` should work, but you being you I'm sure you knew this and didn't want to confuse any newcomers to regex ;)

Comment: @acheong87: Exactly, but there are some regex flavors that have problems with `[][]` (Java for example), so I thought it best not to take any chances. I have no idea what Puppet DSL uses under the hood...